# Spring MVC Step by Step into Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maven

Could someone please help me convert the ANT scripts in

http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part5.html

into MVN?

I'm confused do I still have to make .bat files if I'm manually placing the hsqldb into my pom.xml dependency?

Plus can someone please provide specific samples? Since http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/usage.html provides no such thing

Thanks :)

Comment: It would be easier to help you out if you post what you have done so far, and explain what problems you are having with it

Comment: For the sql-maven-plugin you didn't seemed to read the site very well, cause there two links in the navigation which express "Examples"...so take a look there...

Comment: @mattb I've done chapters 1 to 4, I'm stuck at 5 since it requires hsqldb

Answer (score 3):

I hope these links from Spring's developers help you to porting sample project from Ant to Maven (but these articles about Spring 3):

- http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/17/green-beans-getting-started-with-maven-and-spring/
- http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/02/obtaining-spring-3-artifacts-with-maven/

Comment: @jimmy what samples with hsqldb you need? Add it as dependency, like this: `<dependency><groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId><artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId><version>2.0.0</version></dependency>` and use. BTW, Spring 3.0 simplify working with embeded databases (and also HSQLDB) and take care about many aspects. See for details: http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-3-makes-use-embedded-easy

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've managed to get chapter 5 done.
In your src/test/resources folder place copies of the following files (from previous chapters and this one):

- create_products.sql
- load_data.sql (change the " in the descriptions for ')
- jdbc.properties
- test-context.xml

Now these files are on the classpath so we don't have to worry about making them fully qualified.

Instead of creating the ant scripts for creating and populating the database I simply called the `create_products.sql` script in the `onSetUpInTransaction()` method of the `JdbcProductDaoTests` class.

```
@Override
protected void onSetUpInTransaction() throws Exception{
    super.executeSqlScript("classpath:create_products.sql", true);
    super.deleteFromTables(new String[] {"products"});
    super.executeSqlScript("classpath:load_data.sql", true);
}
```

In the jdbc.properties under the **jdbc.url** property set to `jdbc:hsqldb:filename;shutdown=true;`

After doing this my tests run and I don't have to start the db via the command prompt, I've found filename.script filename.properties for the database but I'm not sure where it is actually storing the data after I insert it to the database.

I guess this is something I can worry about in the next chapter?

Hope this helps.